# Alternative 3d molding techniques at home

Tags: 3d-models, material

i have seen formbox http://golem13.fr/formbox/ and it uses heat and many materials like PVC. Is there any way to do this with paper or paper derivatives(like egg carton)? If the answer is yes, how can i do that?

Comment: You have a bit of vagueness to the question. Does your reference to paper-like material mean the substance used to create the positive form or are you suggesting that the paper-like material would be formed around the positive form? Does your scenario include a previously constructed vacuum box?

Comment: Working principle doesnt matters. i want to make mold of different things by using paper. İt should copy form like a skin

Comment: This question isn't about 3D printing, as such I'm closing to vote it as off-topic.

Comment: @Tom van der Zanden  So explain what is 3d printing. Is it only abs and pla?

Comment: No, FDM (using any material) is just one example of 3D printing. Other techniques include, SLA, SLS, DLP, Binder Jetting,... Roughly speaking, 3D printing is any process in which a model is built-up additively, layer-by-layer. What you've linked to just isn't 3D printing, it's vacuum forming.

Comment: So also you can apply paper layers additively. First of all form than combine different layers. I think you should change your vision.

Comment: There is now [a meta question](http://meta.3dprinting.stackexchange.com/questions/147/hobbyist-machine-questions-on-topic) to discuss the validity of this topic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Forming kinda blister out of paper is possible but not the way it's formed out of plastic. Paper is not elastic, it's bendable but not strechable. It's the issue of how cellulose fibers are formed and how are they entangled.

Anyway - you can create a form out of wet mixed paper pulp. Wrap it around your model and then wait until it's dry. It will form amazingly stiff form. You can do it also out of wet handkerchiefs.

You could build a vacuum machine as in the formbox to squeeze the paper pulp the get water out of the material but the cover should be done out of light silicone film so it would be treated by vacuum.

Comment: wet paper is quite well suited for making molds in the manner you describe. The original model should be treated with some form of mold release to ensure a clean break from the model. It is of course dependent on the material of which the model is constructed.

Fiberglass molding is done by wrapping the model, called the plug with fiberglass saturated with a resin, then encasing that in the equivalent of a plastic bag. Removing the air causes the fiberglass to match precisely the surface of the plug, creating a good mold. It would work with paper pulp too.

Comment: @fred_dot_u removing model from the form is always the case. Formbox or "blistering" in general is easy as the blister itself is flexible somehow. So model can "exceed" general rules. paper form is not as such.